# Problems with regex and BBCode

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

Hello guys I've been trying to make a bbcode thing today but I really can't understand regex, I wanted to transform a html code into a bbcode one, tried several attempts but didn't work at all.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<SPAN STYLE="FONT-SIZE:18PX">Hello</SPAN>
---or---
<span style="font-size:18px">Hello</span>
```

I wanted a regex/replace that would transform it into

```
[size=18]Hello[/size]
```

Is it possible to do just with regex/replace? I tried using some libraries to do it but also didn't succeeded.

Here's the function I've been using

```
function HTMLtoBBCode(text) {
    text = text.replace(/<b>/gi, "[b]");
    text = text.replace(/<\/b>/gi, "[/b]");
    text = text.replace(/<i>/gi, "[i]");
    text = text.replace(/<\/i>/gi, "[/i]");
    text = text.replace(/<u>/gi, "[u]");
    text = text.replace(/<\/u>/gi, "[/u]");
    text = text.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n\r");
    text = text.replace(/<br(.*?)\/>/gi, "\n\r");
    text = text.replace(/<img[^>]*?src="([^"]*?)"[^>]*?>/gi, "[img]$1[/img]");
    text = text.replace(/<font[^>]*?size="?([^">]*?)"?>((?:[\s\S](?!<font[^>]*?size))*?)<\/font>/gi, "[size=$1]$2[/size]");
    return text;
}
```

## Solution:

```
text = text.replace(/<span style="font-size:(\d+)px">([\s\S]*?)<\/span>/gi, "[size=$1]$2[/size]");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could the span have other styles inside it that need to be maintained? i.e. what happens where `<span style="font-size:18px; color:blue;">`

Comment: The span will always be like that, only the numbers will change I'm making an userscript, don't have access to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern:

```
<span style="font-size:(\d+)px">(.+?)</span>
```

Replacement:

```
[size=$1]$2[/size]
```

This assumes the ignoreCase flag.

Comment: Works like a charm, took me a while to figure out how to use it and I had to make a alteration to it but in the end it worked, thanks. (Solution added to the OP)